# tournament question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An ordinary knock-out singles tennis tournament (with no seeds or byes) consists
of a series of rounds. In each round, the remaining players play against each other
in pairs, with the losers being eliminated and the winners going through to the next
round; in the last round, the only two remaining players play the final match to
determine the winner of the tournament.

Suppose that there are 7 rounds.
Before the tournament starts, the organizers need to construct the draw,
which specifies who plays who in the first round, and then which first-round
winners play which other first-round winners in the second round, and so on.
Of course, the organizers don’t know who the first-round winners will be, so
in the draw they are just thought of as “the winner of the match between
player X and player Y”, and so forth. How many possible draws are there?
Use the fact, proved in lectures, that the number of ways to group 2k people
into k pairs is $\frac{(2k)!}{(2^k)k!}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Suppose that you start with $~2^3~$ different people, rather than $~2^7~$ different people, at the start of the tournament.  Then, how many different draws are there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many ways to make $n$ pairs from 2 groups of $n$ people?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459221/how-many-ways-to-make-n-pairs-from-2-groups-of-n-people)